# overwrite DNS domain

Tags: scripting, dns

We have an enum server that sends all naptr request to an enum provider.

The provider only responds back if the domain matches them.  We have several domains and I need to intercept the request change the domain to the providers domain for proper lookup, then change it back.

What is the best way to do this.

so for example client A sends a request to our enum server as:
NAPTR 1.0.8.7.4.2.1.5.5.3.testdomain.com
This should go the carrier as:
NAPTR 1.0.8.7.4.2.1.5.5.3.carrierdomain.com

Comment: The server is running PowerDNS Recursor

Comment: You might be able to do this by running a local DNS override such that you have testdomain.com CNAME carrierdomain.com